# Фоновый режим Андроид WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Всем привет.
Мне нужно что бы приложение андроид работало в фоновом режиме, само приложение состоит из WebView
Создал сервис, но что дальше?

Comment: Сервис и будет работать в фоне. Его можно, например, использовать для показа уведомлений

Comment: Да, но как это сделать с помощью WebView, ведь при сворачиваете браузера уходит в спящий режим

Comment: Код который вы поместите в сервисе будет работать в фоне, делегируйте ему парсинг страницы